# Can't get this schmitt oscillator to work...did I goof somewhere?

Tags: oscillator, schmitt-trigger

Below is my attempt at a schmitt oscillator circuit that uses a 74HC14 and lights up three LEDs in sequence. I built it on some breadboard, but nothing lights up. I'm really at my wits end...can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

[image: Schmitt oscillator circuit]

Comment: Did you use a simulator?  If so change any part by 1%

Comment: I don't have access to a simulator. I was able to get it to work by changing the resistance values in a couple places (one of the LEDs wasn't even being lit up even with a mere 220 ohms, so I removed the current limiting resistor entirely, and it's working now. Just a little experiment, so no need to worry.)

Comment: My answer has a link to a web simulator in any browser ... did you miss it? *Funny thing is that on a* **simulator**, .... but delete your answer  and copy (update) to your question.

Comment: another http://tinyurl.com/yego9vsj

Comment: Thanks Tony, I figured out how to view your simulator. Wish there was a circuit builder that behaved that way and allowed SPICE model integration. There really needs to be a robust and well-designed circuit design and simulation solution. Fritzing just isn't doing it for me.

Comment: Falstad uses ideal Physics so OpAMPs, Caps and Chokes have 0 Ohms ESR or DCR or Zout so you add this when needed.  There is no scope sync but you can change the sampling rate in options and the time base  locked or floating. You can turn any analog parameter into a slider on the side.  So to make it real , you must understand how imperfect each part is for ESR if that matters.  In this case, the only thing that mattered was to make 1 part different by 0.1%

Comment: some builtin circuits are entertaining

Answer (score 3):

You schematic is 100 % accurate.

Funny thing is that on a [simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000044999999999999996%2015.472767971186109%2050%205%2043%0AR%20144%200%20144%20-32%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ac%20144%20112%20144%20144%200%201e-7%203.6063221848642013%0Ar%20288%20-32%20240%20-32%200%20470%0A162%20288%20-32%20336%20-32%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0A183%20192%200%20240%200%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0A183%20288%200%20336%200%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0A183%20384%200%20432%200%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0A183%20336%2048%20384%2048%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0A183%20240%2048%20288%2048%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0A183%20144%2048%20192%2048%200%200.5%201.66%203.33%205%200%0Ag%20432%2048%20432%2080%200%0Ag%20144%20144%20144%20160%200%0Ag%20240%20144%20240%20160%200%0Ag%20336%20144%20336%20160%200%0Aw%20144%2048%20144%20112%200%0Aw%20240%2048%20240%20112%200%0Aw%20336%2048%20336%20112%200%0Ar%20192%20112%20240%20112%200%201000000%0Ac%20240%20112%20240%20144%200%201e-7%200.4326015417183428%0Ac%20336%20112%20336%20144%200%201.0000000000000001e-7%203.7479733825466073%0Ar%20288%20112%20336%20112%200%201000000%0Ar%20384%20112%20432%20112%200%201010000%0Aw%20192%2048%20192%20112%202%0Aw%20288%2048%20288%20112%202%0Aw%20384%2048%20384%20112%202%0Aw%2096%20112%2096%20192%200%0Aw%2096%20112%20144%20112%202%0Aw%2096%20192%20432%20192%200%0Aw%20432%20112%20432%20192%200%0Aw%20192%2048%20192%200%202%0Aw%20288%2048%20288%200%202%0Aw%20384%2048%20384%200%202%0Aw%20240%200%20240%20-32%200%0Aw%20336%200%20336%20-32%200%0Aw%20432%200%20432%20-32%200%0Ab%20128%20-16%20447%2072%200%0A162%20384%20-32%20432%20-32%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20384%20-32%20336%20-32%200%20470%0Ar%20480%20-32%20432%20-32%200%20470%0A162%20480%20-32%20528%20-32%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20528%20-32%20528%20-64%200%0Aw%20528%20-64%20240%20-64%200%0Aw%20240%20-64%20240%20-32%200%0A209%2064%200%2064%2048%200%200.00001%205%201%0Aw%20144%200%2064%200%200%0Ag%2064%2048%2064%2064%200%0Ax%20379%20213%20598%20216%204%2010%20If%5Csyou%5Cscan%5Csimagine%5Csit%5Cs,%5Csyou%5Cscan%5Cssimulate%5Csit.%5CsT.S.%0A403%20464%200%20592%2064%200%203_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_3_3%0Ao%2039%2064%200%204105%205%200.0125%200%202%2039%203%0Ao%2036%2064%200%204097%205%200.0125%200%202%2036%203%0Ao%203%2064%200%204097%205%200.0125%200%202%203%203%0A), if all the thresholds and RC values are identical, **it won't startup** as all LED drivers go high and low at the same time.  This circuit works by the voltage difference between stages and can drive about 7mA.

So just change any part a bit in value and be sure to have a cap across IC for noise reduction and keep wires as short as possible.

[image]

Choose any reasonable RC=T product. I used T=RC=0.1s which with Schmitt thresholds can yield 1.6Hz for 3 stages.

Comment: Aha!

Now I'm getting two LEDs to light up in sequence. I changed the resistance values of one of the LEDs (which is fine for my purposes) and now I'm getting an oscillation.

But...

It's only two of them. The third one isn't lighting up. Not sure why...

Comment: ... bad connection or part? wiring sequence error?. You need some tools like a DMM, Logic Probe. or free .software Scope  and my simulator (interactive and worth the learning curve)

Answer (score 1):

Please draw your schematics so they flow left to right as much as possible. I have redrawn the left portion so it is easy to follow.

[image]

At power-on, all the caps will be discharged, and all the three outputs will be high. All the caps will charge and when they have reached the switching threshold, all 3 outputs will switch nearly simultaneously. This is not what you want, I believe that you want the signal to propagate down the line.

EDIT: Tony is correct, with a mismatch, it theoretically should startup eventually. But, I dislike any circuit that is not guaranteed to startup. It is difficult to make the 3 circuits completely independent, if you have any coupling through the VCC, they may want to lock on to each other and not startup as you want. I built the circuit on a cheap breadboard and even with 2% difference, it won't always startup.

I think you will be better off with a circuit that is guaranteed to oscillate. You can use delays to make the 3 LEDs light in sequence. You will need to fiddle with the values to get each LED to have the same on-time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1iZU6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=222988.0;attach=894252;image

I was attempting to redraw this circuit. Did I goof?

Comment: Patrick Your schematic is too perfect. IF all RC values on a simulator are identical .They might ALL be in Sync so no LEDs turn on.

Comment: @PatrickHennessey - yes you redrew it correctly. But, not everything on the internet is a good design. I consider the original to be a poor design.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a better chance of success if you connect one of the capacitors to V+ rather than ground. Observe polarity. This will create one low output on power up that will ( hopefully) ripple through the others.

The above suggestion will start oscillations, but I am not sure if they will be sustained. Since the goal seems to be to light the LEDs in sequence, I created a circuit that will do this for six LEDs and the same number of parts.[image]
After creating this circuit l realized it is a Johnson counter. The LEDs are numbered in the order they will light when power is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...so the problem was that this oscillator doesn't work unless we introduce a small imperfection somewhere. I can't use all the same resistance values.

I swapped out a resistor, and removed one of them for one of the LEDs, and the whole thing works!

Thanks!